# CloudFlare + Nginx + ngx_http_realip_module

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

We are currently using ngx_http_realip_module to convert CF ip's back to the users'.

It works well for the most part but some ips in our access.log are still from CF.

Current config in http {}:

```
#CloudFlare
set_real_ip_from   199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from   103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from   188.114.96.0/20;   
set_real_ip_from   197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from   198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from   162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from   104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from   172.64.0.0/13;

real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
#real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;
```

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170706-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-Nginx-

What would cause some IPs to not get converted?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you used the full list of IP addresses behind the link on bottom of the article?

Comment: Which IPs specifically are still showing as CloudFlare IPs? Specific examples would help.